# toString() method loads lazy fields in Hibernate

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading

Hibernate. I have a class with a lazy field. I get an entity from db without loading it, but when I use entity.toString() this field is loaded by JPA. How to avoid this behavior? I just want to get null if a field is null.

Comment: Does `toString()` access that field?

Comment: Yes. I want to get null if a field is null.

Comment: `String.valueOf(field)` will give you null

Comment: I meant that after loading entity from db without lazy field I want to use entity.toString() and get null. But jpa is loading it. I understand that it is default behavior. But i want to avoid it.

Comment: 'jpa' doesnt do anything; your jpa provider does, which one?. And only when the object is still 'managed'.

Comment: "loading lazily" is very different from "not loading at all and return an incorrect null value instead of the actual one". Hibernate does the former, not the latter. If you don't want to load a field a property, don't access it. Or use a query that only loads the columns that you want to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate you can check if the field is not initialized:

```
Hibernate.isInitialized(myproperty)
```

Use this method in your toString() implementation.

Comment: Sure but > 70% are using Hibernate so I assumed this could be the case as well.

Comment: Right. I m using Hibernate. And that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. The last question. How do you think, is it a normal practice to use Hibernate.isInitialized(myproperty) in entity.toString() method?

Comment: No. And your case displaying null when it's not initialized is a wrong information. You should log something like "uninitialized" because null means the property is not set (e.g. null in the database)

Comment: Sorry, I do not clearly understand. When you say 'No' you mean it is better not to use it at all in entity.toString()? Or you mean it is normal but I should just log "uninitialized" instead of null?

Comment: Both. Why do you need toString()?

Comment: I want to log the result of service method.             log.info("{} ended in {}ms, with result {}", methodNameWithParams, stopWatch.getLastTaskTimeMillis(), result.toString());

Comment: Ok that's a good idea. But keep in mind that when someone else is using the toString method he may change it so you should document why you use Hibernate.isInitalized.

Comment: Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you redefined the toString () method and included lazy fields. I had such a shocking history. You need to redefine the toString () method without these fields.